# <img height="100%" not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on a newsletter design (which means no use of the CSS background-image property), and I need to use a stretched asset on the left and right side of a table.

So I have this table with 3 cells : one on the left and one on the right for my image that needs to take the whole height of the table, and one on the center with some text.

Issue is that the  isn't taking the entire height of the cell in IE (and Outlook). I've added a red background color to the cell to make sure it's taking the whole height available.

My code is a bit too big to be shown here, but you can see it [live here](http://www.tauziet.fr/temp/parse/newsletter.html)

And here is a JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jXtNE/

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed the link

Comment: Easiest way would be to make the assets 13px wide and ~2000px high, theoretically, you won't hit 2000px high pages.

Comment: I can't do that. That makes my newsletter way too big, as having a fixed size for the img will change the size of the entire table.

Comment: well if it's for email, you can't use any kind of backgrounds. You also can't specify an image as a dynamic size. Not sure you can do what you want, imagine that whatever would work, spammers would use it (and that's the reason backgrounds were removed from email clients, they were abused by spammers)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's doable, as I've checked many email newsletters that were doing the same thing. Just can't figure out why this asset don't want to stretch, even on IE (which is not an email client...)

Comment: use css for this. I'm pretty sure percentual values in html don't even work at all.

Comment: I've tried that. Actually, I've tried both separately, and currently I'm doing both. You can have a look at my JSFiddle to see that http://jsfiddle.net/jXtNE/

Answer (score 0):

Set the padding, margin to 0px; If it not works, just give the negative values to move the margin to the end of the page. For eg -10px. May be this is not a perfect solution. But it temporarily solve your problem.

Comment: <img src="sample.gif" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px"> try this code in your image. "postion:absolute" avoids the unwanted space in IE.

Comment: Always please give your in JSFiddle. It will really easy to help you.

Comment: Check your colspan. They also give result like this.

Comment: I'm not using a colsplan. Really weird issue.